# CSS Change with PHP using Query Strings

Tags: php, html, css, query-string

I want to query an attribute from the URL and hide an element using CSS based on the attribute value.

So I can read the value from the URL:

```
<?php echo $_GET['Produkt']; ?>
```

But how can I wrap it up with a CSS command now?
The value that comes out is the ID of the element that should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the id, one way of doing this is to use a `<style>` tag with some css in the `<head>` section of your page to hide the element:

```
<?php 
$id=$_GET['Produkt']; 
$css='#'.$id.{display:none !important}';
?>
```

$css now contains:

```
 #id{
   display: none !important
  }
```

The `!important` is to overrule stylesheets with the `#id` you eventually later load.

After that, just echo it in the head section:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    <?php echo $css; ?>
    </style>
  </head>
```

Comment: Hello Michel,

thanks for you answer! As a layperson, I have to ask again. I thought it could be covered with one code. In the first code i found out that the first ' before {display:none !important} was missing. Do I have to put the second code in the normal style sheet? Because "id" would not change there, would it? And what is the third code for, or can you not combine the first and third? Sorry for the probably stupid questions but I am completely new to the field 

Comment: You still have to output the css in the `head` section, hence the `echo $css`.